# Replicate EasyNetQ Request/Response with amqplib in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, amqp

I'm replicating EasyNetQ functionality in NodeJS (so that a Node app can communicate with over Rabbit with an EasyNetQ enabled .NET app).  I've replicated EasyNetQ's Publish/Subscribe and EasyNetQ's Send/Receive, but i'm having some difficulty with EasyNetQ's Request/Response.

Here is my current Node code:

```
var rqrxID = uuid.v4(); //a GUID
var responseQueue = 'easynetq.response.' + rqrxID;

Q(Play.AMQ.ConfirmChannel.assertQueue(responseQueue, { durable: false, exclusive: true, autoDelete: true }))
.then((okQueueReply) =>
    Play.AMQ.ConfirmChannel.consume(responseQueue, (msg) => {
        //do something here...
        Play.AMQ.ConfirmChannel.ack(msg);
    })
)
.then((okSubscribeReply) => {
    Q(Play.AMQ.ConfirmChannel.assertExchange('easy_net_q_rpc', 'direct', { durable: true, autoDelete: false }))
    .then((okExchangeReply) =>
        Play.AMQ.ConfirmChannel.publish(
            global.AppConfig.amq.rpc.exchange,
            dto.AsyncProcessorCommand.Type,
            Play.ToBuffer(command),
            { type: command.GetType() },
            (err, ok): void => {
                if (err !== null) {
                    console.warn('Message nacked!');
                    responseDeferred.reject(err);
                }
            }
        )
    )
})
.catch((failReason) => {
    console.error(util.format('Error creating response queue: %s', failReason));
    return null;
});
```

Note that the publish works and is received by the .NET code.  That code then sends a response and the issue is that the response isn't received.  Here's the .NET code:

```
Bus.Respond<AsyncProcessorCommand, AsyncProcessorCommandResponse>(
    request =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got request: '{0}'", request);
        return new AsyncProcessorCommandResponse()
        {
            ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            ResponseType = "ENQResp"
        };
    });
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, but not sure what.  Who can help?

**UPDATE**
I have solved at least part of this.  Taking the value of responseQueue and setting that into the options for publish as "replyTo" hooks the response up - nice.  Now I just have to figure out how to either not create a new queue each time *OR*, make the response queue go away...

**UPDATE FINAL**
So, using the channel setup I had and saving the cinsumerTag (actually, specifying it) allowed me to cancel the consumer and the queue auto-deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking my comments from above to answer this.

There are two pieces to this.  First, from the code above, create your response queue so that it auto-deletes (when the consumer count drops to 0):

```
channel.assertQueue(responseQueue, { durable: false, exclusive: true, autoDelete: true }))
```

Then create/publish to the queue the "server" is listening on - making sure to set "replyTo" for the response queue you just created (the type piece is another bit of ENQ-needed code):

```
{ type: command.GetType(), replyTo: responseQueue }
```

So an entire (currently messy as it's "play" code) method for executing this pattern looks like:

```
private static Request(command: dto.AsyncProcessorCommand): Q.Promise<dto.interfaces.IAsyncProcessorCommandResponse> {
    var responseDeferred = Q.defer<dto.interfaces.IAsyncProcessorCommandResponse>();

    var consumerTag = uuid.v4();
    var rqrxID = uuid.v4();
    var responseQueue = 'easynetq.response.' + rqrxID;

    var handleResponse = (msg: any): void => {
        var respType = null;
        switch(command.Action) {
            default:
                respType = 'testResp';
        }

        //just sending *something* back, should come from 'msg'
        responseDeferred.resolve(new dto.AsyncProcessorCommandResponse(respType, { xxx: 'yyy', abc: '123' }));
    }

    Q(Play.AMQ.ConfirmChannel.assertQueue(responseQueue, { durable: false, exclusive: true, autoDelete: true }))
        .then((okQueueReply) =>
            Play.AMQ.ConfirmChannel.consume(responseQueue, (msg) => {
                handleResponse(msg);
                Play.AMQ.ConfirmChannel.ack(msg);
                Play.AMQ.ConfirmChannel.cancel(consumerTag);
            },
            { consumerTag: consumerTag })
        )
        .then((okSubscribeReply) => {
            Q(Play.AMQ.ConfirmChannel.assertExchange('easy_net_q_rpc', 'direct', { durable: true, autoDelete: false }))
            .then((okExchangeReply) =>
                Play.AMQ.ConfirmChannel.publish(
                    'easy_net_q_rpc',
                    dto.AsyncProcessorCommand.Type,
                    Play.ToBuffer(command),
                    { type: command.GetType(), replyTo: responseQueue },
                    (err, ok): void => {
                        if (err !== null) {
                            console.warn('Message nacked!');
                            responseDeferred.reject(err);
                        }
                    }
                )
            )
        })
        .catch((failReason) => {
            console.error(util.format('Error creating response queue: %s', failReason));
            return null;
        });

    return responseDeferred.promise
}
```